# Contrapositive Proofs with DeMorgan's Law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I have a problem that reads "Suppose a and b are integers. Use proof by contraposition to show that if $4|(a^2 + b^2)$, then $a$ and $b$ are not both odd."

I'm just wondering how to correctly setup the proof. I know I need "~(a and b are not both odd)", so does this mean "a and b are both odd"? Or will DeMorgan's Law apply and make it "a or b is odd"?

| means divides and ~ is negation. I appreciate all and any help.

Comment: Instead of proving that p -> q, you can prove ~q -> ~p instead since they are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the negation would be that both $a$ and $b$ are odd. Consider all the cases: none of $a,b$ are odd; one of them is odd; both are odd. "Not both odd" would be the first two; so the negation is the last one.

For the actual problem: the fact that they are odd means they can be written as $a = 2n+1$ and $b=2m+1$. Then write down $a^2$ and $b^2$ in terms of this expansion. Can you proceed from there?

Comment: Yep! I was just confused if the negation would make it "a OR b" instead of "a AND b". I think I was just overthinking it a little bit. Thanks I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you define:

A: a is odd

B: b is odd

then the claim 'a and b are not both odd' becomes $\neg (A \land B)$ and so the negation of that is simply $A \land B$ i.e 'a and b are both odd'

If it said 'a and b are both not odd', then that would translate to $\neg A \land \neg B$ and the negation of that would be (by DeMorgan) $A \lor B$ i.e 'either a or b is odd' ... but that is not what you are dealing with here.